# How do I get to a UINavigationController sibling view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I have a navigation controller.... and tableview like so:

Item A >
Item B >
Item C >
Item D >
Map >

Clicking on a table cell takes you to the details view for Item X of course.  The map view shows pinpoints for items A-D.  There is a disclosure button on the annotation callout.  The disclosure button code does this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
//Now what???
```

What I would like to do at this point is push the detail view for Item X after popping the map view.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Oh my goodness... I think I figured it out.  I need to set the delegate for the disclosure button to be the table view controller rather than the map view controller?!?  Duh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not proud of this, but... I did come up with a solution.  I set a tag value for the individual annotations based on the index of the array used to set up the tableview.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
//So, we clicked that disclosure button
//TODO: This is really hacky...  What is proper way to do this?
ServicesViewController *vc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];  
[vc infoButtonPressed:control.tag];
```

}

Now in ServicesViewController we can do this:

```
- (void) infoButtonPressed:(NSInteger) index {

// decided against this first step, as graver's answer explains, it does not really make sense
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:false];

//index should be nav array index we want to push
//so simulate a table-row click
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is incorrect. You have a table view:

Item A > (when clicked you push details view for item A) DetailsView (A)
Item B > (when clicked you push details view for item B) DetailsView (B)
Item C > (when clicked you push details view for item C) DetailsView (C)
Item D > (when clicked you push details view for item D) DetailsView (D)
Map > (when clicked push the Map View) Map View > (when you click on the disclosure button you need to push DetailsView for the appropriate item and go one level deeper)

Comment: Appreciate the response, but not what I was asking!  I think I figured it out.  My original comment more or less led me to the answer, which I will post.

Comment: However... having said that, I agree that the required behavior is incorrect.  The behavior you describe would be more in line with standard iOS UI conventions.  It just wasn't what the spec called for.